# How to add a visual feedback on click events on touch devices for websites built with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

It's been long time I'm building websites using HTML5 Boilerplate + Bootstrap but I still didn't figure out how to apply some sort of visual feedback/effect (could be :hover but it's not working) to let the user be aware of clicking a link (for example an item of the mobile menu). Some client started to ask/complain with "I cannot understand what I'm clicking...". I tried adding some coloured background on :hover, on :focus, but none of them are working...
How to do?!

Comment: Please provide what you've tried so far! :-) It'll show the users that you are serious and enthusiastic!

Comment: Try adding some code, you will get instant response :)

Comment: No need for code. Just go to the official Bootstrap website with a smartphone. Open the mobile menu, click one link and no visual feedback will be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add this library: jquery.mobile.min.js

JAVASCRIPT:

```
// simulate hover effect on touch devices
$('a.add_hover_effect').on('tap', function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('hover_effect');
});
$('a.add_hover_effect').on('touchend', function(e) {
    $('a.add_hover_effect').removeClass('hover_effect');
});
```

CSS:

```
a.add_hover_effect.hover_effect {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: I will prepare un JSFiddle as soon as I can.

Comment: Or you can use a small jQuery plugin https://github.com/guruwanabe/actionFeedback